# Работа с Uri. Как в ссылке различить файл?

Tags: c#, .net

Есть такой Uri

```
var uri = new Uri(@"c:\SomeFile.txt");
```

в этом случае uri.IsFile вернет True

Но мне этого недостаточно. У меня могут быть ссылки 3х типов:

- Локальный файл (или файл в сети)
- Файл в интернете (без file:\\ например http://my.ru/file.doc)
- Ссылка в интернете (просто страница при запросе которой я получу нечто в html формате)

Я пока не разбирался, что дальше мне делать с полученной ссылкой, но, полагаю, для начала надо определить ее принадлежность? Как это сделать?

Если я начал не с того, направьте на правильный путь :)

Comment: Отличить по ссылке "файл в интернете" от "страница в интернете" нельзя. Вам никто не мешает "страницу в интернете" скачать как файл. Максимум что можно - это сделать запрос (например, только head) и посмотреть в хедеры. Есть там указано что это html страница, тогда наверно это ссылка.

На крайний случай можно просто смотреть на расширение. Если там html/php/shtml - это ссылка, если doc, pdf, txt - файл.

Comment: Для начала определитесь, что есть ссылка на файл. В моем случае я считаю, что это ссылка на файл с расширением и без всяких ?=

Comment: Не надо смотреть на расширение - это против стандарта!

Comment: @KoVadim, да причем тут html/php и бла бла бла? Ссылка может и такой http://my.ru или такой http://my.ru/index/12 а результатом будет страница html

Comment: @iRumba я знаю, как работает http. Но вполне возможно, что для решения конкретной задачи расширения может быть достаточно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исходя из самого URL отличить файл от страницы - невозможно.

Но можно попытаться это сделать исходя от заголовков, которые вернет сервер в ответ на запрос.

Если сервер считает, что по некоторому адресу находится файл, который можно загрузить - он пошлет заголовок `Content-Disposition` в формате

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=name.ext
```

Правильно распарсить этот заголовок можно при помощи класса [`System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.mime.contentdisposition(v=vs.110).aspx).

Также есть вариация `Content-Disposition: inline` - это тоже файл, но не для скачивания, а для отображения в окне браузера. Причислять такие файлы к файлам или к страницам - решать вам.

---

Но задумайтесь: зачем вы вообще разделяете файлы и страницы? Начать надо с того, откуда у вас ссылка и зачем она вам нужна. Если пользователь отдал вам ссылку - то в большинстве случаев вас вообще не должно волновать ничего кроме содержимого ответа сервера, ведь разницы между файлами и страницами никакой нет.

Comment: Спасибо, суть уловил. Теперь по вашему "зачем". Мне нужно получить текст из переданного пути. Каким образом - другой вопрос. Но передать могут как локальный путь, так и путь к файлу в интернете или просто страница. Мне нужно разобраться что это и прочитать содержимое

Comment: @iRumba ну и зачем вам отличать файл от страницы? Скачивайте и получайте текст.

Comment: хм... а зачем скачивать c:\file.txt?

Comment: Локальный - не надо, его надо просто открыть. Я про ссылки говорил. Вам не надо отличать ссылку на файл от ссылки на страницу перед скачиванием.